# Dealing with image sizing in Blueprint

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I'm very new to Blueprint, as in started this morning, but one thing that struck me is the 'problem' of fixed width content like an image.  What do I do if the image is wider than the columns it resides in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Blueprint specifically, but you could try

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```